# How to fix error 'Could not find the main bundle' while uploading app to the App Store

Tags: xcode, app-store, xcode11, imessage-extension, xcode10.3

I'm constantly trying to upload my iMessage App in the App Store, but I'm receiving an error. It's not my first time uploading an app, but it's the first time seeing an error like this.

> **App Store Connect Operation Error**
>
> Could not find the main bundle or the Info.plist is missing a
> CFBundleIdentifier in
> '/var/folders/hq/_r68cczs6hnchc97ytz4g4bm0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~hdsT8V/Packages/Starman
> Stickers MessagesExtension.ipa'.

[image]

I'm using `Xcode 10.3`. If you need more information to provide, please let me know.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying almost everything, finally, I found the solution.

*The issue occurred cause:*

I accidentally created the project on `Xcode 11 Beta` then I tried to submit it to the App Store from `Xcode 10.3`. I couldn't submit it from `Xcode 11 Beta` cause Beta versions don't support uploading apps to the App Store. So, I had to wait till the `Xcode 11 GM Seed` release, or submit it from `Xcode 10.3`. To mention the second option (Submitting from `Xcode 10.3`) caused this error.

*Solution*

If anyone occurs a similar problem, or somehow makes a mistake like I did (Creating a project on `Xcode Beta` version), then there are 2 solutions.

**Solution 1:**

Wait till `Xcode GM Seed` release, only then you can submit the same project.

**Solution 2:**

If you don't have time to wait for `Xcode GM Seed` then you should create a new project on nonBeta version of `Xcode`.
So, I created a new project on `Xcode 10.3` and copied everything from the older project.